# Implementation of Delete operation in a Binary Search Tree in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have written a program, that will take two filenames as arguments, f1 and f2, both files with numbers.
The program should be callable as follows: tree f1 f2

f1 has millions of unique numbers, one per line. Each number should be read and inserted in a **Binary Search Tree**.

After these are inserted, the program should read numbers from the second file. For each number, the following has to be done:

- Search for the number in the tree
- If it exists, ask the user and delete it from the tree

Now, my code for insertion and searching, is giving correct results, but, in the part of deletion, there is some error.

Please help me out by modifying my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

struct node *insert (struct node *root, int item)
{
    struct node *temp, *temp1, *pre;

    temp = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    temp->info = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;

    if (root == NULL)
        root = temp;
    else {
        temp1 = root;
        while (temp1 != NULL) {
            pre = temp1;
            if (item < temp1->info)
                temp1 = temp1->left;
            else
                temp1 = temp1->right;

        }
        if (item < pre->info)
            pre->left = temp;
        else
            pre->right = temp;
    }

    return root;
}

struct node *create (struct node *root)
{
    int num;
    root = NULL;
    FILE *fp1 = fopen ("myFile1.txt", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf ("cannot open this file");
        exit (0);
    }

    while (fscanf (fp1, "%d", &num) == 1)
        root = insert (root, num);

    return root;
    fclose (fp1);   /* (note: unreachable code) */
}

struct node *min (struct node *ptr)
{
    struct node *current = ptr;

    while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}

struct node *delete (struct node *root, int n)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;

    if (n < root->info)
        root->left = delete (root->left, n);
    else if (n > root->info)
        root->right = delete (root->right, n);
    else {
        if (root->left == NULL) {
            struct node *p;
            p = root->right;
            free (root);
            return p;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL) {
            struct node *p;
            p = root->left;
            free (root);
            return p;
        }

        struct node *p;
        p = min (root->right);
        root->info = p->info;
        root->right = delete (root->right, p->info);
    }

    return root;
}

void search (struct node *root)
{
    int Y, X;
    struct node *t;
    t = root;
    char ch = 'n';
    FILE *fp2 = fopen ("myFile2.txt", "r");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        printf ("cannot open this file");
        exit (0);
    }
    X = 0;
    while (fscanf (fp2, "%d", &Y) == 1) {
        while (t != NULL && X == 0) {
            if (Y == t->info) {
                X = 1;
                break;
            } else if (Y < t->info)
                t = t->left;
            else
                t = t->right;
        }

        if (X == 1)
            printf (" %d is found %d\n", Y, X);
        printf ("if you want to delete a number ");
        scanf ("%c", &ch);
        if (ch == 'y') {
            root = delete (root, Y);
            return root;

        }
        else
            printf ("%dNot found %d\n", Y, X);

    }
    fclose (fp2);
}

void inorder (struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        inorder (root->left);
        printf ("%d ", root->info);
        inorder (root->right);
    }
}

void main ()
{
    struct node *root = NULL;
    struct node *ptr = NULL;
    root = create (root);
    inorder (root);
    search (root);
    inorder (root);
}
```

Comment: Some error? What is the error?

Comment: did you step through with a debugger?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
 int info;
 struct node *left, *right;
};
struct node* insert(struct node* root, int item)
{
 struct node *temp,*temp1,*pre;
 temp =  (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 temp->info = item;
 temp->left = temp->right = NULL;

 if (root == NULL)
 {
    root=temp;
 }
 else
 {
   temp1=root;
   while(temp1!=NULL)
   {
           pre=temp1;
           if(item<temp1->info)
           {
               temp1=temp1->left;
           }
           else
           {
               temp1=temp1->right;
           }
   }
   if(item<pre->info)
   {
      pre->left=temp;
   }
   else
   {
      pre->right=temp;
   }
 }
 return root;
}

struct node *create(struct node *root)
{
   int num;
   root=NULL;
   FILE *fp1=fopen("myFile1.txt","r");
   if (fp1 == NULL)
   {
        printf("cannot open this file");
        exit(0);
   }
   while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&num)==1)
       root=insert(root,num);
   fclose(fp1);
   return root;
}
struct node * min(struct node* ptr)
{
        struct node* current = ptr;
        while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

        return current;
}
struct node* delete(struct node* root,int n)
{
   if(root==NULL)
   {
       return root;
   }
   if(n<root->info)
   {
       root->left=delete(root->left,n);
   }
   else if(n>root->info)
   {
       root->right=delete(root->right,n);
   }
   else
   {
          if(root->left==NULL)
          {
               struct node *p;
               p=root->right;
               free(root);
               return p;
          }
          else
          if(root->right==NULL)
          {
                struct node *p;
                p=root->left;
                free(root);
                return p;
          }

          struct node *p;
          p=min(root->right);
          root->info=p->info;
          root->right=delete(root->right,p->info);
   }
   return root;
}

void search(struct node *root)
{
      int Y,X;
      struct node *t;
      char ch='n';
      FILE *fp2=fopen("myFile2.txt","r");
      if (fp2 == NULL)
      {
          printf("cannot open this file");
          exit(0);
      }
      while(fscanf(fp2,"%d",&Y)==1)
      {
            t = root;
            X = 0;
            while(t!=NULL && X==0)
            {
               if(Y==t->info)
               {
                     X=1;
                     break;
               }
               else
               {
                 if(Y<t->info)
                 {
                     t=t->left;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     t=t->right;
                 }
               }
            }

            if(X==1)
            {
              printf("\n%d is found\n",Y);
              printf("\nDo you want to delete %d (y/n): ",Y);
              scanf(" %c",&ch);
              if(ch=='y')
              {
                 root=delete(root,Y);
              }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n%d Not found %d\n",Y,X);
            }
      }
      fclose(fp2);
 }

 void inorder(struct node *root)
 {
          if (root != NULL)
          {
               inorder(root->left);
               printf("%d ", root->info);
               inorder(root->right);
          }
 }

 void main()
 {
       struct node *root = NULL;
       struct node *ptr = NULL;
       root=create(root);
       inorder(root);
       printf("\n");
       search(root);
       printf("\n");
       inorder(root);
       printf("\n");
 }
```

Apart from minor changes of formatting, following are the major changes:

- Always remember to put `{}` braces for each **control statement** (if, while, else etc.) even if it has one operation, because later, code may be added to the same **control statement** and forgotten braces would mean that the **control statement** would not be applied to that code. For e.g. you forgot the braces in:

  ```
  if(X==1)
   printf(" %d is found %d\n",Y,X);
   printf("if you want to delete a number ");
   scanf("%c",&ch);
   if(ch=='y')
   {
     root=delete(root,Y);
     return root;
   }
   else
    printf("%dNot found %d\n",Y,X);
  ```

  Now because of the missing braces, the else is being applied to `if(ch=='y')` instead of `if(X==1)`.
- Secondly, whenever you initialize a condition variable to a value and the check on it, is inside a nested loop, and the operation is to be repeated for several inputs or cases, the initialization also needs to be done inside the loop. Same was the case with `t = root;` and `X = 0;` in `search` function, they were just set once and when the next number was read from the file, they were not initialized again.
- You called `return root;`, in `void search(struct node *root)` function, which is of return type `void`, meaning it returns **nothing**:

  ```
  if(ch=='y')
  {
   root=delete(root,Y);
   return root;
  }
  ```

  and also, a `return` call means, that the function will stop further execution, then and there, and the remaining code, below the `return` call, will not be executed, which is not what you want, as was in:

  ```
  struct node *create(struct node *root)
  {
   int num;
   ...
   while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&num)==1)
    root=insert(root,num);
   return root;
   fclose(fp1);
  }
  ```

  here, `fclose(fp1);` would never get called.
- And, last but not the least, better indentation of code can help understand where the scope of each control statement lies, instead of having to track each opening brace `{` to its closing one `}`.

Answer (score -1):

There are several additional areas where you want to avoid causing problems for yourself in the long run. You want to avoid *hardcoding filenames* in the main body of your code, much less hardcoding filenames buried in functions. If you need to operate on a file, such as you do it `create` or `search`, pass a `FILE*` parameter (or filename) to the function. This will make your code much more maintainable and reusable. For `create` you would do something similar to:

```
struct node *create (struct node *root, FILE *fp)
{
    int num;
    root = NULL;

    while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &num) == 1)
        root = insert (root, num);

    return root;
}
```

For your current `search` you could do something like:

```
void search (struct node *root, FILE *fp)
{
    int v;

    while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &v) == 1) {

        struct node *t = root;
        char ch = 'n';

        while (t != NULL) {
            if (t->info == v) {
                printf ("\n%d is found\n", v);
                printf ("\nDo you want to delete %d (y/n): ", v);
                scanf (" %c", &ch);
                if (ch == 'y') {
                    root = delete (root, v);
                }
                break;
            } 
            else {
                if (v < t->info)
                    t = t->left;
                else
                    t = t->right;
            }
        }
        if (!t)
            printf ("\n%d Not found\n", v);
    }
}
```

But why are you passing a `FILE *` pointer to `search` to begin with? Shouldn't `search` just search through your tree and return a pointer to the node containing a matching value (if it exists) or `NULL` otherwise? That would certainly make `search` a general function to be used in many different circumstances with your tree, rather than a one-off check for matched values from a second file.

How then to approach obtaining the filename information required by your code? Just as you pass the required parameters to each function you call in your code, you can pass required information to `main` the same way. `main` takes arguments given on the command line and passes them to your program. The general form of `main` is:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

(you will also see the equivalent form `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` which simply reflects an alternate form for `argv` without showing the results of the array conversion to pointer that takes place automatically when an array is passed as a function argument)

Use arguments to get information to `main` instead of hardcoding. That doesn't mean you cannot provide *default* filenames in your code that will be used if no arguments are provided. You can make use of the *ternary* operator which is basically a shorthand `if-else` statement of the form `(condition) ? true_value : false_value`. With it you can take filenames from the command line while still providing default values for the filenames to be used in the event no arguments are provided (note: the first argument will always be used as `fp1`). e.g.:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp1 = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "myfile1.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen (argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "myfile2.txt", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot open fp1\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot open fp2\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

You can then pass the `FILE*` pointers (`fp1`, `fp2`) to any function that needs them, e.g.:

```
root = create (root, fp1);
```

Having removed the hardcoded filenames from `create` and `search`, you can turn your attention to creating a `search` that is more useful than just checking for matching values from the second file. Rewriting `search`, it needs only take a pointer to `root` and the value to be searched for, it can then return an indication of whether the value was found in your tree (generally a pointer to the node containing the value) or not, returning a `NULL` pointer. For example:

```
struct node *search (struct node *root, int v)
{
    struct node *t = root;

    while (t != NULL) {
        if (t->info == v)
            return t;
        else {
            if (v < t->info)
                t = t->left;
            else
                t = t->right;
        }
    }
    return t;
}
```

To complete your code in a maintainable way, you only need write a function that will read the values from the second file, `search` your tree, and then prompt to allow deletion if the value is found. Again, it only needs as parameters a pointer to `root` and a `FILE*` pointer to read values from. It can then handle calling `search` and `delete` from there. (note: `delete` can be rewritten to operate directly on the pointer returned by `search` to avoid a second traversal, but that is for another day). For example, your check and prompt to delete function could be:

```
void check_delete (struct node *root, FILE *fp)
{
    int v;

    while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &v) == 1) {

        char ch = 'n';

        if (search (root, v)) {

            printf ("\n%d is found\n", v);
            printf ("\nDo you want to delete %d (y/n): ", v);
            scanf (" %c", &ch);

            if (ch == 'y')
                root = delete (root, v);
        }
        else
            printf ("\n%d Not found\n", v);
    }
}
```

Putting all the pieces of the puzzle together, and providing *function prototypes* above `main` (which would ultimately be moved to a proper header file along with the struct) and the function *definitions* below (which would ultimately be moved to a separate source file), you would end of with something similar to the following code. Note, this is not intended to be an exhaustive rewrite containing all suggested changes or improvements, but it is important to begin handling the information needed by your code in a correct manner and avoid falling into bad habits early. Let me know if you have any further questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

/* function prototypes */
struct node *insert (struct node *root, int item);
struct node *create (struct node *root, FILE *fp);
struct node *min (struct node *ptr);
struct node *delete (struct node *root, int n);
struct node *search (struct node *root, int v);
void check_delete (struct node *root, FILE *fp);
void inorder (struct node *root);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp1 = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "myfile1.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen (argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "myfile2.txt", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot open fp1\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "cannot open fp2\n");
        return 1;
    }
    struct node *root = NULL;

    root = create (root, fp1);
    fclose (fp1);

    inorder (root);
    putchar ('\n');

    check_delete (root, fp2);
    fclose (fp2);
    putchar ('\n');

    inorder (root);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}

struct node *insert (struct node *root, int item)
{
    struct node *temp, *temp1, *pre;

    temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);
    temp->info = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;

    if (root == NULL) {
        root = temp;
    } 
    else {
        temp1 = root;

        while (temp1 != NULL) {
            pre = temp1;
            if (item < temp1->info)
                temp1 = temp1->left;
            else
                temp1 = temp1->right;
        }

        if (item < pre->info)
            pre->left = temp;
        else
            pre->right = temp;
    }

    return root;
}

struct node *create (struct node *root, FILE *fp)
{
    int num;
    root = NULL;

    while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &num) == 1)
        root = insert (root, num);

    return root;
}

struct node *min (struct node *ptr)
{
    struct node *current = ptr;
    while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}

struct node *delete (struct node *root, int n)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        return root;
    }
    if (n < root->info) {
        root->left = delete (root->left, n);
    } else if (n > root->info) {
        root->right = delete (root->right, n);
    } else {
        if (root->left == NULL) {
            struct node *p;
            p = root->right;
            free (root);
            return p;
        } else if (root->right == NULL) {
            struct node *p;
            p = root->left;
            free (root);
            return p;
        }

        struct node *p;
        p = min (root->right);
        root->info = p->info;
        root->right = delete (root->right, p->info);
    }
    return root;
}

struct node *search (struct node *root, int v)
{
    struct node *t = root;

    while (t != NULL) {
        if (t->info == v)
            return t;
        else {
            if (v < t->info)
                t = t->left;
            else
                t = t->right;
        }
    }
    return (t);
}

void check_delete (struct node *root, FILE *fp)
{
    int v;

    while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &v) == 1) {

        // struct node *t = root;
        char ch = 'n';

        if (search (root, v)) {

            printf ("\n%d is found\n", v);
            printf ("\nDo you want to delete %d (y/n): ", v);
            scanf (" %c", &ch);

            if (ch == 'y')
                root = delete (root, v);
        }
        else
            printf ("\n%d Not found\n", v);
    }
}

void inorder (struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL) {
        inorder (root->left);
        printf ("%d ", root->info);
        inorder (root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: The author asked to correct the mistakes, with regards to **deletion**, in his/her code, which were a few in place changes, not to revamp the entire code. Although, you have given excellent pieces of advice, but they do more than simply addressing the author's query, which could cause confusion for later viewers or for the author too.

Comment: Who are you? I've had to correct your sloppy edits all day. You worry about your answers cluttered with unnecessary variables and I'll worry about mine -- deal?

Comment: This is no hate game. I just expressed what I thought. What "sloppy edits" and "answers cluttered with unnecessary variables" are you talking about? I don't get you.

Comment: In my edits, I just fixed the grammar and left the code as it is, while you have re-indented the code. Both edits are for different purposes and were essential.

Comment: Perhaps there is a language barrier. The sloppy edits are your reformats to code in posts that leave multiple blank lines between brackets, etc.. If you are going to go to the trouble to clean up somebody else's code, at least make it succinct and readable for the next person who may be inclined to help. Your corrections to `search` left `X` which serves no purpose other than to duplicate what a test of `t` tells you to begin with and the preservation of *upper-case* is largely contrary to accepted C style. Now we have both said our piece, let's move on.